# sending long line of text in email

Tags: c#, email

I have to send a string of text via email... but the receiver is very demanding about its format: it has to be plain ASCII text.

I've tried sending as `Content-Type: text/plain; charset="us-ascii" Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable`. Unfortunately, my string is pretty long (255 characters) and quoted-printable cuts this string after 78 characters to new line:

> BUOYID,55073,UTCDATE,24/06/2015,UTCTIME,22:42.00,STATUS,E0000,ZEROCRS,201,A=
>   VGHGT,0.92,TZ,6.4,MAXWAVE,3.12,SIGWAVE,1.63,SIGPERIOD,9.3,H10,2.2,T10,9.5,M=

Apparently the solution lies in sending the text as a `ContentDisposition.Inline` attachment (attachment with content within body), which would allow a longer text string... but it's not so easy.

If I save the string to a text file, like so:

```
string message ="my255CharText";
using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"\\shareddata\temp\buoy.txt"))
{
    file.WriteLine(message);
}
MailMessage emailMsg = new MailMessage();
emailMsg.To.Add("email@destination.com);
emailMsg.Subject = "my Subject";
emailMsg.From = new MailAddress("email@source.com");
emailMsg.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII;
emailMsg.IsBodyHtml = false;

Attachment data = new Attachment(@"\\shareddata\temp\buoy.txt", MediaTypeNames.Text.Plain);

emailMsg.Attachments.Add(data);
ContentDisposition dispositon = data.ContentDisposition;
dispositon.Inline=true;
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("SMTP_SERVER");
smtp.Send(emailMsg);
```

I keep sending email with attached file not content of text file in the body.
If I try to put the variable as an attachment:

```
 Attachment data = new Attachment(message, MediaTypeNames.Text.Plain);
```

I get the following:

`PathTooLongException: The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters.`

I've also tried to change the path to local disk (`c:\temp\buoy.txt`) but file is still sent as an attachment, not inline.

EDIT: please let me make it clear: I receive the `pathTooLongException` ONLY when I'm sending the variable directly as an attachment, NOT when I'm sending from file.

Comment: Ok. Can you please try saving the `message` in a file that is NOT a shared file? Say in `C:\files\buoy.txt`.

Comment: I've changed path to c:\temp\buoy.txt - file is still sent as an attachment. The "path too long" shows only when I'm trying to send it directly from variable `Attachment data = new Attachment (string message,....)`

Comment: Sending formatted data via e-mail is always fraught with issues.  Apart from the formatting issues, it is also not guaranteed delivery and it is insecure (can be easily spoofed or intercepted).  I would recommend using either web services or SFTP/FTPS to transfer the data.

Comment: You are possibly right, but email is the only way the recipient can collect the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I solved it: as @Dan Field pointed, partial problem was laying in Ms Outlook stubbornly displaying inline attachment as.. well attachment. But that wasn't solving my problem with breaking lines, which in the end was the fault of the [Quoted-printable standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quoted-printable#Quoted-Printable_encoding), which indeed limits the line size.
But, at least for my purpose the 7bit encoding was acceptable and with it I was able to send whopping 262 characters in one line:

```
string message="255CharsLongMessage";
using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"\\shareddata\temp\buoy.txt", false, System.Text.Encoding.ASCII))
        {
            file.WriteLine(message);
        }


MailMessage emailMsg = new MailMessage();
emailMsg.To.Add("destination@server.com");
emailMsg.Subject = "My_Subject";
emailMsg.From = new MailAddress("source@email.coom");
emailMsg.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII;
emailMsg.IsBodyHtml = false;
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("SMTP_SERVER");
Attachment data = new Attachment(@"\\shareddata\temp\buoy.txt", new ContentType("text/plain; charset=us-ascii"));

emailMsg.Attachments.Add(data);
data.ContentDisposition.Inline = true;
data.TransferEncoding = TransferEncoding.SevenBit;
smtp.Send(emailMsg);
```

Answer (score 0):

So I don't know if this really resolves your actual problem, but to get rid of the error you're dealing with now this should work:

```
string message ="my255CharText";

MailMessage emailMsg = new MailMessage();
emailMsg.To.Add("email@destination.com);
emailMsg.Subject = "my Subject";
emailMsg.From = new MailAddress("email@source.com");
emailMsg.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII;
emailMsg.IsBodyHtml = false;

using (System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message)))
{
    Attachment data = new Attachment(ms, new ContentType("text/plain; charset=us-ascii"));

    emailMsg.Attachments.Add(data);
    ContentDisposition dispositon = data.ContentDisposition;
    dispositon.Inline=true;
    SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("SMTP_SERVER");
    smtp.Send(emailMsg);
}
```

When I test this, Outlook and the Android Mail client display the attachment as an attachment, GMail (web and Android client) shows it inline (as a single line of text).  But on my phone's smaller screen, obviously the text gets broken up on a few lines.

I have a feeling you're dealing with a rendering issue that's going to be specific to the email client, and your work may be more dealing with that **particular** client rather than coming up with a universal solution (which probably doesn't exist).

Comment: In provided format it underlines the `Attachment data` as an `Invalid initializer member declaration`. If I drop the `using` and simply declare `ms` and use it as an attachment, I receive blank email with "text/plain" attachment - I've checked it both in Outlook and Gmail.

Comment: Sorry, dropped a closing paren in there (on the using line) - edited to fix.  That's why the problem was there. As I noted, some clients will just show it as an attachment even though you specify it's inline.  It's up to the client to decide how to render an inline attachment.

Comment: Hmm, it seems that this time my SMTP server refuses to process this message :/ - I get `Failure to send the email` :(